# join sql query to analyze values

Tags: sql, join

I have a table `entries` with three columns: `id, name, display_name`.
I need to write a query with join, which will check how many display_names there is for each name and display only those names, which have multiple display_names.
This should be fairly simple to write with joins. Before I used next query:

```
SELECT e1.name 
FROM entries e1 
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e2.display_name) 
  FROM entries e2 
  WHERE e2.name = r1.name
) > 1;
```

Comment: if your query does what you need, what's the question?

Comment: question is: how do I write it with join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a join.

```
SELECT e1.name 
FROM entries e1 
GROUP BY e1.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Note that you can use an alias in a having clause, so borrowing from @Scorpi0 and @Widor you can also do:

```
SELECT e1.name, COUNT(DISTINCT e1.display_name) as occurrences
FROM entries e1 
GROUP BY e1.name
HAVING occurrences > 1
```

The reason this is allowed is that `having` is evaluated after all the other stuff in the select is done. By that time the contents of the alias will be known.
You cannot use this alias in the `WHERE` clause because that runs (or may run) **before** MySQL knows what in the alias.

Comment: Thanx for the **group by** and **having** clue.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a join, the HAVING clause could do the filter for you:

```
SELECT e1.name 
FROM entries e1 
GROUP BY e1.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e1.display_name) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(display_name)
FROM entries
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(display_name) > 1
```